# Error recibiendo datos del servidor

Tags: javascript, rest, post

Estoy empezando un proyecto para conectar a un servidor socket y no consigo que funcione. Os pongo el código y me explico.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var direccion = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/miurl';
    new Vue({
        el: '#main',
        data: {
            datos: [],
            Usuario_Cod: '',
            Usuario_Nom: '',
            Usuario_Token: ''
        },
        methods: {
            getUsuarios: function (usuario, clave) {

                var headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'123123123123ASDFASDF',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
                };
                var jn = {
                    Cmd: "Login",
                    User: usuario,
                    Pass: clave
                };

                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: direccion,
                    data: JSON.stringify(jn),
                    config: 'Content-Type:"application/json"' //{ headers }
                }).then((response) => {
                    alert('Mensaje OK');

                    /* Codigo comentado temporalmente
                     this.datos = response.data;
                     this.Usuario_Cod = this.datos.Usuario.Codigo;
                     this.Usuario_Nom = this.datos.Usuario.Nombre;
                     this.Usuario_Token = this.datos.Usuario.Token;
                     */
                }).catch(alert('Mensaje Error'));
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Le envio estos datos a un servidor socket (pulsando un boton con el evento v-on:click) y el servidor lo recibe y devuelve un json correcto y con la respuesta `200 OK`, pero se dispara el `catch` con el mensaje "*Mensaje Error*". Acepto el error e in mediatamente se dispara el `then` con el mensaje "*Mensaje OK*".

Si elimino el `catch`, no se dispara el mensaje "*Mensaje OK*".
En el primer caso, mientras está en pantalla el mensaje de error, en la consola del navegador veo que si que se ha recibido correctamente el mensaje 200 junto al json. Cuando pulso el boton del error, sale en mansaje de OK y al pulsar este se borra de la consola el evento POST y parece que se recarga la página.

La cabecera de respuesta en el navegador es esta:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers authorization, origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 911
Content-Type application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date Wed, 25 Apr 2018 12:09:09 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Server Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.11
```

Me he quedado atascado aqui.
Gracias a todos

Comment: puedes usar el enlace de [edit] para añadir o arreglar cualquier cosa en tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de usar la API es:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: direccion,
  data: JSON.stringify(jn),
  config: 'Content-Type:"application/json"'
})
.then(function(){...})
.catch(function(){...});
```

Pero en el `.catch()` tienes:

```
.catch(alert('Mensaje Error'));
```

Eso lo que hace es invocar inmediatamente el `alert` y el resultado pasarlo al `.catch()`, cuando aun nisiquiera se ha enviado la solicitud al servicio.

Debes agregar una funcion ahi no invocarla directamente:

```
.catch(function(){
    alert('Mensaje Error');
});
```